# setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled in Compatibility Library

Tags: android, android-support-library

In my app I have a some fragments that I switch between manually in the phone version and I want to show the `<` arrow in the `ActionBar`.  To do this I know I need to call `actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` but that breaks in lower api levels. I can check the api level and only call it in 3.0+ but LINT gives me an error.  Is it alright to just suppress the error?  What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First setup ActionBarSherlock for compatibility for Android 2.1+ for the ActionBar:

http://actionbarsherlock.com/

https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock

One you have set up this great compatibility library, you can now use in your `Fragment`:

```
getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
```

Make sure you extend your Fragments to SherlockFragments:

```
public class TestFragment extends SherlockFragment
```

If you need anymore help, let me know I have set this up many times!

Regards,

Comment: I was initially thinking I would just have it revert back to the old look and fell in older versions of Android but I think you're right! I'll use ActionBarSherlock. Thank you!

Comment: No problem, Jake Wharton, has other great compatibility libraries as well!

Answer (score 2):

Use Jake Wharton's action bar sherlock library which is more flexible to support in all versions.

https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock

Answer (score 0):

If you need use the actionbar in android 3 and higher only, you can suppress warnings (be shure that min api level is set). But else you have to use SharlockActionBar library.